# screenfull ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I am using screenfull in my react js project. The screenfull is giving me this error when the page is loaded. If I do instant refresh when this lib is loaded in the file the first time then it works but as soon as I refresh the entire page it gives this error in
"ReferenceError: document is not defined"

I am using this lib
https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull

Answer (score 0):

This is a React issue, please use the `document` references inside this `If block`

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // your Code here
}
```

If this doesn't work, please provide some code samples from which I can check

Comment: It doesn't work as there is an import line mentioned right at top of the code. Have to take entire code with import statement in different file

Comment: That's a bit unclear brother, can you please explain it more with code examples so that I can explain

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the new version of lib reverting back to 5.2 works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).